# ThreeJS: Unsupported geometry type "TextGeometry" error when I refresh

Tags: javascript, three.js

i'm newbie, probably i miss something but I'd really like some help.I'm trying to add 3d text object to editor with this code:

```
newTextButton.onClick( function () {

    var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
    loader.load( 'fonts/Open Sans_Regular.json', function ( font ) {
    var textboxVal = textObj.getValue();
        var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
            color: 0xffffff
        });
        var textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry( textboxVal, {
            font: font,
            size: 1,
            height: 0.1, curveSegments: 3,
            weight: 'normal'
        });

        var textMesh = new THREE.Mesh( textGeo, material );
        textMesh.name = 'Text ' + ( ++ meshCount );

        textMesh.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );

        editor.execute( new AddObjectCommand( textMesh ) );

    });

} );
```

it works fine but after I add the text when I refresh the page, editor removes all objects and I get an error like this:

> THREE.ObjectLoader: Unsupported geometry type "TextGeometry"
>   THREE.ObjectLoader: Undefined geometry 10899F30-4C7F-4ECD-9A0F-C8D6236326B2
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bones' of undefined(…)

Should I write something about ObjectLoader or is my code wrong?

Comment: does this work if you do this? var textboxVal = "Hello World";

Comment: yes, it does...